# How to update a column of every row in a sql table with the value of that column from another specific row in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have a table called dummy that looks like

```
A | B | C | D | E
------------------
1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | u1
1 | 2 | 4 | 3 | u2
1 | 2 | 4 | 3 | u3
```

I've decided that every row needs to have the same `C` column `WHERE E = u1`.  So I would end up with:

```
A | B | C | D | E
------------------
1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | u1
1 | 2 | 3 | 3 | u2
1 | 2 | 3 | 3 | u3
```

To do this I ran the following query:

```
update tb1 
set tb1.C = tb2.C
from dummy as tb1, dummy as tb2
where tb2.E = 'u1'
```

I was just curious if this is the best way to do something like this in SQL Server.

Comment: You could use explicit JOIN,but this a simple query it doesnt need optimization.

Comment: We would hope the engine would be smart enough to limit the results of tb2 before it executes the join which could result in a large Cartesian product.  If it's not, then doing an inner join and placing the limit of E on the join may be more efficient.  but testing would have to be done to know.  It really depends on the database version patches as to how the engine will processes this.  Great question though.  I thought about a sub-select but doing it for each row could be worse performance.  Again, only way to know is testing.  Try all 3 methods and look at execution plans!

Comment: One other item to know if C has different values for the same value of E then your query wouldn't work.  as tb2 would return multiple values. The three answers posted so far all provide you with a value of C, which may not be the one you want.  If you know you only have 1 value of E being u1 then its a non-issue.  However if you have multiple your solution would fail and the three answers posted either provide you with the max of C or a random value of C.

Comment: @xQbert . . . What do you mean "will not work"?  If there are multiple matches, SQL Server will choose an arbitrary matching value for the update.

Answer (score 1):

**Test Data**

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (A INT,B INT,C INT,D INT,E VARCHAR(2))
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES
(1,2,3,4,'u1'),(1,2,4,3,'u2'),(1,2,4,3,'u3')
```

**Update Query**

```
UPDATE @TABLE 
SET C = (SELECT TOP 1 C 
         FROM @TABLE
         WHERE E = 'u1')
```

**Result Set**

```
SELECT * FROM @TABLE

╔═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦════╗
║ A ║ B ║ C ║ D ║ E  ║
╠═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬════╣
║ 1 ║ 2 ║ 3 ║ 4 ║ u1 ║
║ 1 ║ 2 ║ 3 ║ 3 ║ u2 ║
║ 1 ║ 2 ║ 3 ║ 3 ║ u3 ║
╚═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
update dummy set C = (SELECT TOP 1 C FROM  dummy WHERE E = 'u1')
```

Comment: opss didnt see your post until I had posted mine :S

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH x as
(
  SELECT e,c, MAX(CASE WHEN E = 'u1' THEN c END) OVER () newc
  FROM tb1
)
UPDATE x 
SET c = newc
WHERE e <> 'u1'
```